# Proper way to send response on a failed JS Fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I've got a request that I'm performing using the Javascript Fetch API and I'm trying to implement error handling.

I've implemented the following function:

```
export async function fetchFoo() {
    const data = await fetch(`http://localhost:9090/foo`, {
        method: "GET",
        redirect: "follow",
    })
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
        })
        .then(async (res) => await res.json())
        .catch(() => undefined);

    return data;
}
```

I call this function from a React component and then display the data. I'm a bit confused on *what* I should return in cases where there is an error? Currently, I am just returning `undefined` and displaying an error on the frontend. However, this approach feels incorrect, what is the appropriate type of data to send back to the caller?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by restructuring the way I was handling the requests. Instead of performing any sort of operation in a `catch` I instead caught the error on the handler function call and did my desired behavior there.

Answer (score -2):

its typical that the backend returns an error message that you can forward to the user. Another possibility is to check the statuscode of the response, and if a 4XX Response, return an error message based on the type of error.

Comment: If your response is an object, how do you handle that on the frontend? Do you check `if ('error' in response)`? Fetch doesn't always return a response code, so I don't think I can rely on that (e.g. user network issues).

Comment: the backend should be able to always return the same field when there is an error (e.g. "Error": "this did not work, please try again later". You can then check for this field. you can also check for missing responseCode (if !responseCode)

Comment: I'm referring to cases where the request never reaches the backend, in this case a javascript error is thrown. I am trying to determine how to pass data back to the calling function and then display an error. 

If I'm returning an error object, do you just check for that object property in the caller every time you make a request?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).